# ContourPlot of a discontinuous function

Tags: plotting

```
rainbow = {"Rainbow", {1.7, 3.4}};
color = ColorData[rainbow];
cf = Function[{z}, Directive[Opacity[0.8], ColorData[rainbow][z]]];
plot = {AspectRatio -> 1,
ImageSize -> {400, 400},
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
FrameLabel -> {x, y},
LabelStyle -> Black,
FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.002], FontSize -> 14],
Mesh -> None, MeshStyle -> Gray,
InterpolationOrder -> 0,
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> cf};

g[x_, y_, z_] := Piecewise[{{(x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1/16, (x - 1/2)^2 + y^2 - 1/16 <= 0 && z >= 0}}, z];
(*t is a function of x1 and x2, and it is a discontinuous function as shown in the Figure 1*)
t[x1_, x2_] := Module[
            {center, line, surface, intersection, interPoint, d, data},
            center = {0, 0, 1};
            line = Line[{{x1, x2, 0}, center}];
            surface = ImplicitRegion[g[x, y, z] == 0., {x, y, z}];
            intersection = MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[line, surface];
            interPoint = Nearest[intersection, center][[1]];
            d = EuclideanDistance[center, interPoint];
            time = 2 d;
            time
            ];
data = Table[t[x, y], {y, -1, 1.0, 0.05}, {x, -1, 1.0, 0.05}];
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Evaluate@plot]
```

[image: Figure 1]

You don't need to read `Module` carefully, t[x,y] is only a function of x and y and it is discontinuous at the region as shown in Figure.

Then I want to plot some contourplot lines. For example:

```
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.3, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

and it looks like Figure 2(a). But what I want is Figure2(b), because of the discontinuous region.

[image: Figure2]

1. How to modify the code to plot Figure2(b)?
2. There is no problem when I run the `ListDensityPlot` , however, there is a warning when I run `ContourPlot`:

Nearest::near1: "MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[Piecewise[{{<<2>>}},z]==0.,{x,y,z}],Line[{{x,y,0},{0,0,1}}]]]] is neither a list of real points nor a valid list of rules"

Why?

3. In the `ListDensityPlot` If the code is

   data = Table[t[x, y], {x, -1, 1.0, 0.05}, {y, -1, 1.0, 0.05}];

The plot is rotated 90 degress with what it should be. I have to change the code to

```
data = Table[t[x, y], {y, -1, 1.0, 0.05}, {x, -1, 1.0, 0.05}];
```

Why?

Problem 2 and 3 are not important. They didn't have an effect on the results, I am just curious about it.

This is my solution:

```
Show[ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 1.8, {x, 0.3, 0.7}, {y, -0.2, 0.2}, ContourStyle -> color[1.8], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0,  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 1.9, {x, 0.2, 0.8}, {y, -0.3, 0.3},  ContourStyle -> color[1.9], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.0, {x, 0.2, 0.8}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}, ContourStyle -> color[2.0], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1, Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.1, {x, -0.33, 0.85}, {y, -0.33, 0.33},  ContourStyle -> color[2.1], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1,  Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.2, {x, -0.46, 0.9}, {y, -0.46, 0.46},  ContourStyle -> color[2.2], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0,  Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.3, {x, -0.57, 0.9}, {y, -0.57, 0.57}, ContourStyle -> color[2.3], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0,  Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.4, {x, -0.67, 0.9}, {y, -0.67, 0.67},  ContourStyle -> color[2.4], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0, Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.5, {x, -0.76, 0.9}, {y, -0.76, 0.76}, ContourStyle -> color[2.5], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0,  Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}],
ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.6, {x, -0.84, 0.84}, {y, -0.84, 0.84}, ContourStyle -> color[2.6], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0, Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}]]
```

[image]

I define the `color=ColorData[{"Rainbow",{1.7,2.7}}]`

Comment: It's quite okay & normal to post an answer to your own question.  (IMO, it's better than including an answer in the question itself).

Answer (score 4):

A simply way to obtain the desired plots is to excluding portions of the curves in the discontinuous region.  Precisely where `t` is discontinuous does not seem well defined, so I have taken it to be approximately the almost circular region shown in the first plot in the question.  Then,

```
nodiscontinuity = ContourPlot[{t[x, y] == 2.3, t[x, y] == 2.5, t[x, y] == 2.7}, 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 20,
    MaxRecursion -> 1, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (x - .57)^2 + (y - .01)^2 > .08]]
```

[image]

Superimposing this plot on the result of

```
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Evaluate@plot];

Show[%, nodiscontinuity]
```

then shows that the curves indeed lie just outside the apparent discontinuous region.

[image]

(Note that plot (b) in the Question does not lie entirely outside the discontinuous region.)

In answer to the other two questions, the error messages occur because `ContourPlot` is calling `t` with symbolic input before calling it with numerical input.  And, replacing

```
data = Table[t[x, y], {y, -1, 1.0, 0.05}, {x, -1, 1.0, 0.05}];
```

by

```
data = Table[t[x, y], {x, -1, 1.0, 0.05}, {y, -1, 1.0, 0.05}];
```

rotates the plot produced by `ListDensityPlot`, because the second line of code produces the `Transpose` of the array produced by the first line of code.  This can be undone by

```
ListDensityPlot[data // Transpose, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Evaluate@plot]
```

reproducing the original, not rotated plot.

**Addendum**

In comments below, [Qi Zhong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38755/qi-zhong) asked whether his creative solution above could be computed more rapidly.  This can be accomplished by calling `ContourPlot` fewer times.  However, the `2.1` contour still must be computed separately, because it requires much higher resolution.  On my PC, the final plot in the Question require 230 sec, but

```
Show[ContourPlot[t[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
    Contours -> DeleteCases[Range[1.8, 2.6, 0.1], 2.1], ColorFunction -> (White &), 
    Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}, 
    ContourStyle -> (Directive[color[#], Thickness[.005], Opacity[1]] & /@ 
    Range[1.8, 2.6, 0.1]), MaxRecursion -> 1], 
    ContourPlot[t[x, y] == 2.1, {x, -0.33, 0.85}, {y, -0.33, 0.33}, 
    ContourStyle -> color[2.1], PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
    Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}}]]
```

requires only 106 sec.

Comment: Yeah, I know this can work. The problem is I need to find the range of x manually. And in fact, I have several lines to plot, such as t[x, y] == 2.4,2.5... I will consider your method. But, is there any better one?

Comment: I found the exact function of the edge, Exclusions -> {{4 (x + 2)^2 == 19 (x^2 + y^2 + 1), x >= 3/8}} and it works. The third problem: normally, we should write {x,-1,1,0.1} before {y,-1,1,0.1} in Table, right? But when I do this, it seems the plot is not what I think it should be. Then I have to write y first.  Is there any way to solve the second problem.

Comment: Another thing, it will take about >5 minutes to run the code I add above. Is it normal or is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: @QiZhong  Nice solution.  It can be made faster, and I shall provide an approach when I return late this evening.

Comment: @QiZhong  As requested, I have addressed your two comments in my updated answer.  Best wishes.